# Ajax and dynamic url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, url

I have been following a tutorial on javascript and php and modifying it to my own personal tastes.
I've run into something i dont know how to fix, and i cant find anything online to help me fix it either.

The tutorial in question has shown me how to create and ajax module i can call from any php script to do its bidding. however the tutorial simply had the ordinary file paths of "index.php" or "signup.php", but i went ahead and out of my own personal preference, i used $_GET includes to display my pages via "index.php?page=signup"

the tutorial ajax module is:

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

now when i use a form to call this function to send data to php, it just sends me back to index.php without the dynamic url in place. im not sure what i need to place into the function call. the tutorial had:

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
```

I just dont know what to use besides "signup.php in the case of having the url being index.php?page=signup but nothing i've tried seems to work, and im starting to question if the error actually has anything to do with the ajax function.

Please assist a nooby noob in this dilemma.

Comment: I would recommend you the javascript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is very simple to use and will help you to achieve your goal in short time. And it is xBrowser - so you won't have any problems with different browsers.

Comment: Yes you can use jQuery library to avoid browser compatibility issues in such cases.

Comment: Ok i believe i have verified that the ajax script is actually working, because it tells me when a username is valid or not after checking the database. so the issue is that when i hit submit on the registration page, the page goes to "index.php?"